# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound is ignoring Audio Session category, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audiotoolbox

I'm developing audio app and I'm facing the problem with system sound services (AudioToolbox.framework) and audio session category.

I have set audio session category to AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, which should consider iphone's silent switch.

- But when I'm using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() function the silent mode is ignored and iphone's volume level is ignored too.
- When I'm using AudioServicesPlayAlertSound() function the silent mode and iphone's volume level is considered as expected.

Could you please tell me somebody what is going on? Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

For a lot of research I came to decision that this behaviour is an apple bug in implementation. If you find in this topic something new please let me know.